# Adding results to a numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, binary

I am using python-3.x, and I want to create a numpy array called result_array that hold the binary result from each loop (minimum_arrray)

```
# The code:
import random
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
i = 0
ii= 0
e = 2
y = 2
x = 2
bin_arrray_size = 5
# result_array = np.ndarray(shape=(), dtype=int)
# result_array = np.ndarray(shape=(), dtype=int)
for ii in range (e):
    bin_arrray = np.random.randint (2, size=(bin_arrray_size, y*x))
    print ("bin_arrray:" '\n', bin_arrray)

    flot= np.zeros ((bin_arrray_size, 1))
    for i in range (bin_arrray_size):
        X = bin_arrray[i]

        decimal=int(''.join(map(str,X[:].tolist())), 2)
        flot[i]  = (decimal * 2.324)

#        print ("flot:" '\n', flot)
    for flot in np.nditer(flot, flags=['external_loop','buffered'], order='F'):
        print (" the flot :" '\n', flot)
    minimum_arrray = bin_arrray[flot.argpartition(0)[:1]]

    print ("Minimum_arrray:" '\n', minimum_arrray)
#   result_array = np.vstack (result_array, minimum_arrray)

print ("bin_arrray type:" '\n',type(bin_arrray))
print("bin_arrray shape:" '\n', bin_arrray.shape)
print ("flot type:" '\n', type(flot))
print("flot shape:" '\n', flot.shape)
print ("minimum_arrray type:" '\n', type(minimum_arrray))
print("minimum_arrray shape:" '\n', minimum_arrray.shape)
```

```
 ########## the Result #######
bin_arrray:
 [[1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1]]
 the flot :
 [ 18.592   2.324   9.296  11.62   25.564]
Minimum_arrray:
 [[0 0 0 1]]         ################ First result
bin_arrray:
 [[0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0]]
 the flot :
 [  9.296  11.62    2.324  20.916  18.592]
Minimum_arrray:
 [[0 0 0 1]]          ################ Second Result
bin_arrray type:
 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
bin_arrray shape:
 (5, 4)
flot type:
 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
flot shape:
 (5,)
minimum_arrray type:
 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
minimum_arrray shape:
 (1, 4)
```

I have tried this befor the loop:

```
result_array = np.random.random((2,4))
```

and this

```
result_array = np.ndarray(shape=(), dtype=int)
```

after the loop

```
result_array = np.vstack (result_array, minimum_arrray)
```

but none of them worked

What I want to see a new array called (result_array) and look like this:

```
result_array:
    [[0 0 0 1]
    [0 0 0 1]]
```

Comment: `result_array = np.array([result_array, minimum_arrray])` should work.
`np.vstack` takes a tuple as input `np.vstack((result_array, minimum_arrray))`

Comment: @Eskapp I get this error `NameError: name 'result_array' is not defined` i don't know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stack numpy arrays as follows:

```
result = np.zeros((0, 5))
for i in range(3):
    array = np.random.rand(1, 5)
    result = np.vstack((result, array))
```

Now `result` is:

```
array([[ 0.23537172,  0.71615064,  0.04694777,  0.76896748,  0.34270846],
       [ 0.90591311,  0.90446305,  0.31865153,  0.79437811,  0.29033377],
       [ 0.2967733 ,  0.01044752,  0.43947452,  0.10285084,  0.29054507]])
```

The pitfall is to call `vstack` with multiple arguments instead of one tuple (as Eskapp mentioned).

**Edit:** In terms of efficiency (and maybe also readability) you'd better construct a large 3x5 `result` array and assign its rows within each iteration. But in your simple case, stacking might work as well.

Comment: However, it is now advised to use `np.stack` instead of `vstack` with an extra argument for the axis. :)

Comment: @Eskapp: Not sure how to do this in a loop, since `stack` introduces a new dimension each time.

Comment: @Falko This works great, but the type of the new array `result` is `float64` is there any way to make it `int64`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is inefficient and can be simplified.

At first write a simple function which converts binary arrays of arbitrary precision into an array of ints. These can be done a a simple calculation with is a lot faster and easier to understand than your string conversion and casting process.
    #This will interpret the binary array as an unsigned int, if you want to convert your binary array to an int you have to make some modifications. 
    def bin2int(bin_array):
        decimal=np.zeros(bin_array.shape[0],dtype=np.int)
        n=bin_array.shape[1]

```
    for i in range(0,n):
        decimal+=bin_array[:,n-i-1]*2**i

    return decimal
```

Now to the main part. You can use vstack to combine to arrays, but in every iteration the two arrays will be copied, which is slow. Don't use array stacking in a for loop if performance is of any concern. Only Python Lists can be extended efficiently not numpy arrays.

```
result_array=np.zeros((e,y*x),dtype=np.uint8)
for ii in range (e):
    bin_array = np.random.randint (2, size=(bin_array_size, y*x))

    decimal=bin2int(bin_array)
    flot=decimal*2.324 #I don't know why you need this multiplication

    result_array[ii,:]=bin_array[np.argmin(flot),:]

print(result_array)
```

An example of some other useful functions when working with binary data (numpy.packbits, numpy.unpackbits)

Feel free to ask if you have any further questions.